# Pyspark [WinError 2]

Tags: python, windows, pyspark

I have installed pyspark from `pip` and from `standalone`, I always get the same error when launching pyspark from shell

```
C:\Users\user>pyspark
Python 3.7.8 (tags/v3.7.8:4b47a5b6ba, Jun 28 2020, 08:53:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programme\Spark\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\shell.py", line 38, in <module>
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized()
  File "D:\Programme\Spark\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 320, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "D:\Programme\Spark\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 98, in launch_gateway
    proc = Popen(command, **popen_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
```

Comment: Install spark too.

Comment: i have done it but always the same

Comment: i have download spark, install from pip

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have not installed the `pyspark` module, as it is giving a `module not found` error. Just fire up this command in terminal -->

```
pip install pyspark
```

Comment: Show your pip installation output.

Comment: i have use this and all requirement is already satisfied. But i don't know why i get the same error all the time

Comment: already done. I have spark binary and it give me the error above. I install pyspark from PIP but i'm facing the same error

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling with `pip` in CMD with Admin permissions.

Answer (score 0):

In your error message,

```
[MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

So, I suspect the software doesn't match the architecture.

Or your PATH is not set well, and then the system cannot find the `pyspark` or `spark` binary. The error message in English

```
The system cannot find the file specified
```

tells you that.

---

From the `pyspark` [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyspark/),

> The Python packaging for Spark is not intended to replace all of the other use cases. This Python packaged version of Spark is suitable for interacting with an existing cluster (be it Spark standalone, YARN, or Mesos) - *but does not contain the tools required to set up your own standalone Spark cluster.* You can download the full version of Spark from the Apache Spark downloads page.

You should download spark from the [spark website](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html).

Comment: I have done it but i get the same error. Even using PIP

Comment: install spark binary, set the SPARK_HOME and use findspark to find the spark binary.